# Building Hyperlinked Words in a String like "Sales | Inventory | Customers" in Excel

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I have multiple sheets in my Excel workbook namely Sales, Inventory, Customers, etc. I need to build one single string having a format like "Sales | Inventory | Customers" allowing to jump to a sheet depending on what word I click in this string. It is pretty easy to hyperlink individual cells pointing to each of the sheets but that is not what I need. I need to use one cell only and have a string in it which will provide links to desired sheets i.e. something like "Sales | Inventory | Customers". I tried using...

```
=HYPERLINK("[MyWB.xlsx]Sales!A1","Sales") &" | " &HYPERLINK("[MyWB.xlsx]Inventory!A1","Inventory") &" | " &HYPERLINK("[MyWB.xlsx]Customers!A1","Customers")
```

...but it didn't work. HYPERLINK is working fine just for one sheet though.

Comment: The `HYPERLINK` is a cell function. Its result will be the content of the whole cell. And the `HYPERLINK` function is supposed to create **one** hyperlink. So the `HYPERLINK` function can create **one** hyperlink per cell only.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. Is there a way to achieve what I need?

Comment: As far as I know, in Excel it is not possible to link different text parts in **one** cell to multiple link targets. There are multiple approaches (search keys: `excel multiple links one cell`) using embedded Word objects or using VBA in combination with accelerator keys to select which target will be chosen. But in my opinion all those are not recommendable. Simply use multiple cells for multiple hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0):

From [http://excel.tips.net](http://excel.tips.net/T002805_Putting_More_than_One_Hyperlink_in_a_Cell.html)

1) Create a list of keywords in a Word document.
   Within Word, specify the hyperlinks for each keyword.

2) Select the list of keywords and press Ctrl+C to copy it to the Clipboard.
In Excel, choose cell and Paste Special.
Paste Special dialog box. [image: Paste special pop up]

3) Choose Microsoft Word Document Object in the list of pasting formats.

4)Click on OK and Try.

It works for me :)

steps for future availability may be link get 404 error ;)

Comment: Thanks @Monica. This seems complicated and links would have external  dependencies. I need to distribute the workbook to other users with links working seamlessly.

Comment: where is your workbook ? its work for me. you don't need to save word file you created just for linking we using it and then just copy and special paste in you excel. and its work. nothing complicate in this one. if you want more then normal cell function then this is the way.